# Learn-Rails Tut Error: NoMethodError - undefined method `login' for GoogleDrive:Module:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets-api

Here are the first lines of the server output:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `login' for GoogleDrive:Module:
  app/models/contact.rb:16:in `update_spreadsheet'
```

Here is the contact model (contact.rb):

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_no_table

```
column :name, :string
column :email, :string
column :content, :string

validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :content
validates_format_of :email,
:with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"])
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
    if ss.nil?
        ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.name
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.email
    ws[last_row, 4] = self.content
    ws.save
  end
end
```

Bounced the server and double-checked for typos (including making sure I had the right ENV variables in the application.yml file) but I am still running into the error.

Comment: You need to figure out where "GoogleDrive" is coming from and ask the author what happened to the "login" method. Generally, you should avoid username/password authentication as it's about to be disabled by Google.

Comment: I'm following the Learn-Rails tutorial by Daniel Kehoe. One of the gems installed was google_drive. That leads me to what I need to do - I am using an older version of the book from 2013. This lead me to go here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/google_drive/versions

I changed the specific gem to gem 'google_drive', '0.3.6' since it was using 1.0 - then the error I received was an authentication error. Changed the settings on my test Gmail account and it works now. Thanks for helping me figure that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm following the Learn-Rails tutorial by Daniel Kehoe. One of the gems installed was google_drive. That leads me to what I need to do - I am using an older version of the book from 2013. This lead me to go here: rubygems.org/gems/google_drive/versions I changed the specific gem to gem 'google_drive', '0.3.6' since it was using 1.0 - then the error I received was an authentication error. Changed the settings on my test Gmail account and it works now. Thanks for helping me figure that out!

Comment: cool. Do note the comment at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#about_authorization_protocols which says "You must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests." Username/password auth will soon be end-of-lifed